# Three reflection theorem in the context geometry on the sphere

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Recently, I study geometry on the sphere in Patrick Ryan's Geometry book.

A line on the unit sphere $S^2$ is defined as
\begin{equation}
l=\{x\in S^2: <x,z>=0\}
\end{equation}
for some point $z\in S^2$. A point $z$ is called the pole of $l$.
A reflection to line $l$ which is defined as
\begin{equation}
\Omega_{l}x=x-2<x,z>z
\end{equation}
where $z$ is the pole of $l$ and $x\in S^2$.

My problem is proving the following theorem:
Let $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ be three lines through a point $P$. Then there is a unique line $\delta$ through $P$ such that
\begin{equation}
\Omega_{\alpha}\Omega_{\beta}\Omega_{\gamma}=\Omega_{\delta}.
\end{equation}

My partial answer:
Let the pole of $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ be $N_{\alpha},N_{\beta}$ and $N_{\gamma}$ respectively. Then after some calculation I get

\begin{equation}
\Omega_{\alpha}\Omega_{\beta}\Omega_{\gamma}=x-2<x,N_{\gamma}>N_{\gamma}-2<x,N_{\beta}>N_{beta}-2<x,N_{\alpha}>N_{\alpha}
+4<x,N_{\gamma}>
<N_{\gamma},N_{\beta}>N_{\beta}+4<x,N_{\gamma}><N_{\alpha},N_{\beta}>N_{\alpha}+
+4<x,N_{\beta}><N_{\alpha},N_{\beta}>N_{\alpha}
-8<x,N_{\gamma}><N_{\gamma},N_{beta}><N_{\gamma},N_{\alpha}>N_{\alpha}
\end{equation}

Comment: Hint: Is the composition orientation preserving? Dies it fix a point on the sphere? Also, try to prove this first for reflections in the Euclidean plane.